# .NET 4 - Determine the number of touch points available in Win 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, .net-4.0, multi-touch

Windows 7 reports the number of touch points available to the system under the computer properties - is there a way to get that info in .NET 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 exposes this via [GetSystemMetrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385(VS.85).aspx)(SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES).  Since you need this in C#, you need to use P/Invoke:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

const int SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES = 95;

int GetPointsAvailable()
{
    return GetSystemMetrics(SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES);
}
```